# Python flask URL mapping issue, returning 404

Tags: python, flask

```
-->project
    --->run.py
    --->config.py  
    --->readme.md 
    --->app
        --->__init__.py
        --->controllers
            --->__init__.py
            --->test_controller.py
        --->model
            --->__init__.py
            --->test_model1.py
            --->test_model2.py
```

**run.py**

```
from app import app
app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 8080, debug = True)
```

**config.py** - All configuration variable

**app/__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
```

**controllers/__init__.py** - Empty

**controllers/test_controller.py**

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
    def test():
    return "Hello world"
```

When I start my server form run.py the server gets started.
But when I try the URL http://locahost:8080/test, it returns 404.
But **if the route is configured in app/`___init__`.py it is working**.

Can anyone please guide me what is incorrect here in configuration.
I want to keep the above structure, please let me know of any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you import the file containing the `@app.route` decorator, it won't be registered. Flask won't import and register all `.py` files automagically for you.

At the end of your `__init__.py` file in `app/`, import `projectname.controllers`, and import `test_controller` in the `__init__.py` file in the `controllers` module.